# Where did I go wrong in this integration $\int\frac{\ln(1-e^x)}{e^{2x}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Here is the closest I've come to [the answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20ln%281-e%5Ex%29%2Fe%5E%282x%29)

[Link to Wolfram equality](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2*e%5E%28-2x%29*%28e%5Ex%2Be%5E%282x%29*ln%281-e%5E%28-x%29%29-ln%281-e%5Ex%29%29%20%3D%20-1%2F%282*e%5E%282x%29%29*%28ln%281%20-%20e%5Ex%29%2Be%5E%282x%29*x-e%5Ex-e%5E%282x%29*ln%281-e%5Ex%29%29) not giving **true** as output

**NB!** I marked where I'm unsure in $\color{red}{red}$ color. And please don't get startled because of the wall of equation, it's simply a more tedious integration in my opinion.

$$\int\frac{\ln(1-e^x)}{e^{2x}}\,dx$$
let: $e^x= u \iff dx=\frac{1}{u}du$
$$\int\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u^3}\,du = -\frac{\ln(1-u)}{2u^2} - \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u^2(1-u)}\,du$$

This can be written as
$$-\frac{\ln(1-u)}{2u^2}-\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\color{red}{\frac{A}{u}+\frac{B}{u^2}-\frac{C}{1-u}}\right)\,du\qquad\qquad(1)$$

where $A,B,C$ is determined through setting
$$\frac{1}{u^2(1-u)} = \color{red}{\frac{A}{u}+\frac{B}{u^2}-\frac{C}{1-u}}$$

By multiplying with LHS denominator and factoring RHS I get

$$1 = (-A-C)t^2+(A-B)t+B \implies B = A = 1 \land C = -1$$

This put into $(1)$ gives us

$$-\frac{\ln(1-u)}{2u^2}-\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{u^2}-\frac{-1}{1-u}\right)\,du$$

and

$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u^2} + \ln(u) - \frac{1}{u}+\int\frac{1}{1-u}\,du\right)$$

another substitution $w = 1-u \iff du = -dw$ gives us

$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u^2} + \ln(u) - \frac{1}{u}-\int\frac{1}{w}\,dw\right)$$

Finally this is equivalent to

$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u^2} + \ln(u) - \frac{1}{u}-\ln(w)\right) + C$$

Substitution back to x and factoring gives us

$$-\frac{1}{2e^{2x}}\left(\ln(1-e^x) + \color{red}{e^{2x}\cdot x} - e^x - e^{2x}\ln(1-e^x)\right) + C$$

Comment: @graydad Remove your comment please; makes it looks like I have the right answer heh :P

Comment: how come $\int\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u^3}\,du = -\frac{\ln(1-u)}{2u^2} - \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u^2(1-u)}\,du$?

Comment: @eaxdpiotnyeantial The equivalence relation for integration by parts. Did I use it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u^3}\,du$$
$$I=\frac{\ln(1-u)}{-2u^2}-\int\frac{1}{2u^2(1-u)}$$
Now, $$\frac{1}{u^2(1-u)}=\frac{1}{u^2}+\frac1{u}+\frac1{(1-u)}$$
So:
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u^2}-\left(-\frac1u+\ln u-\ln|1-u|\right)\right)+c\\
I=\frac{1}{2e^{2x}}\left(-\ln(1-e^x)+e^{x}-e^{2x}x+e^{2x}\ln|1-e^x|\right) + c$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a question; should I get in the habit of always putting $\ln|x|$ instead of $\ln(x)$ when integrating?

Comment: @XMLParsing i think $\int dx/x=\ln|x|+c$ but $d(\ln x)/dx=\frac1x$

Comment: $d(ln(x))dx = 1/x$ for positive $x$. And for negative $x$, we have $d(ln(|x|))/dx = d(\ln(-x))/dx = 1/(-x) \cdot (-1) = 1/x$.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is right !

$$\ln(|1-e^x|)-x=\ln(|1-e^x|)-l(e^x)=\ln(|1-e^{-x}|)$$

and here is the wolfram solution.

Comment: So I get that $\ln\frac{1-e^x}{e^x} = \ln(e^{-x}-1)$, how does it become $\ln(1-e^{-x})$ though?

Comment: because when you integrate $\frac{1}{x}$, you obtain $\ln(|x|)$. So $|e^{-x}-1|=|1-e^{-x}|$.

Answer (score 0):

After "This put into (1) gives us", the sign of 1/(1-u) changes from triply negative in the next line to doubly negated in the following line.

Comment: Fixed it, but I'm still not getting the right answer.

Comment: Does it help that $x-\log(1-e^x)=-\log(e^{-x}-1)=i\pi-\log(1-e^{-x})$

Comment: Well, that did clarify one thing. But explain why my answer still equality in Wolfram still doesn't come up as **True**

Link in body text for this Wolfram input!